# RabbitMQ Metrics Not found

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, monitoring, prometheus

I'm running the latest RabbitMQ on docker, and I am trying to get RabbitMQ's metrics to use it with prometheus but with no success.
When I access host.docker.internal:15672/metrics I get the following response

> {"Error":"Object Not Found","reason":"Not Found"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why my answer has been deleted by @Jean-François Fabre, but let me quote the official rabbitmq site where it says that by default prometheus metrics are exposed on port 15692:

> Notice that RabbitMQ exposes the metrics on a dedicated TCP port, 15692 by default.

Source: https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html#rabbitmq-configuration